# How to output floating point numbers with a custom output format in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, iostream

The problem is that I want to output Mathematica compatible floating point numbers. The only difference with the standard IOStream or printf output format is that the exponential `e` is replaced by `*^`:

```
Standard C/C++ output format: 1.23e-4
Mathematica format: 1.23*^-4
```

Is there a way to manipulate streams to achieve this effect? My original idea was just to use istringstream and dump it to a string and then replace all the `e`'s. I would also be okay if someone posted code to parse through the bits of the floating point number and output it directly (i.e. a `printf("%e")` replacement).

Comment: If you're just trying to read this into Mathematica, it can definitely handle the e+- format. For example, `ReadList[<filename>, Number]` will convert them appropriately.

Comment: I prefer not to use ReadList since I do a lot of quick on-the-fly copying and pasting into Mathematica (saving the data to a file would be a waste of time). I have had similar problems arise in the past where the target format wasn't Mathematica. I am looking for an actual way to manipulate the standard format.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Just figured I'd throw it out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea should work out easily:

```
std::string FloatToStringMathematica(float x) {
  std::stringstream a;
  a << x;
  std::string u = a.str();
  size_t pos = u.find("e");
  if(pos != std::string::npos) {
    u.replace(p, 1, "*^"); 
  }
  return u;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was waiting for something better, but I guess that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

printf with %f shouldn't use scientific notation at all. Is there some reason you must use this notation and not simply output a long enough string to fit all significant figures?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use streams as the OP requested, nonetheless using [`frexp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/frexp/) works for me:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Print x for import to Mathematica
void cout_print(double x)
{
    int exp;
    cout << frexp( x, &exp );
    if( exp ) cout << "*2^" << exp;
}

int main()
{
    cout.precision(numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
    cout_print(3.25); // 0.8125*2^2
}
```

This just expresses the number using a base-2 exponent instead of 10.